# Vue js recognize selected option

Tags: vue.js

I have cities object which contains `city.name` and `city.id`. Also I have `cameras` object which has city_id: `cameras.city_id`. In my html:

```
<div v-for="camera in cameras">
    <select v-model="camera.city_id" class="form-control">
        <option v-for="city in cities" selected>@{{ city.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I have to recognize which element of object should be marked as selected, simply said mark element as selected if `city.id == camera.city_id`. It will be true only once per loop. How do I manage that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `value` on the options like this:

```
<div v-for="camera in cameras">
    <select v-model="camera.city_id" class="form-control">
        <option v-for="city in cities" :value="city.id">@{{ city.name }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Done that way, the proper `option` will automatically be selected for you by the `v-model` directive.

See this for more information: http://vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Select